# find Variables in a module

Tags: ibm-doors

I'm new to DXL and I want to extract the variables containing

```
_I_,_O_ and _IO_
```

from a module and export then to `csv` file. Please help me with this

EG:
`ADCD_WE_I_DFGJDGFJ_12_QWE and CVFDFH_AWEQ_I_EHH[X]` is set to some value

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This question has two parts.

1. You want to find variables that contain those parts in their name
2. You want to export to a .csv file

Another person may be able to expand on a better way, but the only way coming to mind right now for 1. is this:

Loop over the attributes in the module (for ad in m do {}) and get the string of the attribute names.

I am assuming that your attributes are valued at _I_, _O_ or _OI_?  Like alpha = "_I_"?  Are these enumerate values?
If they are, then you only need to check the value of each object's attribute.  If one of those are the attribute values, then add it to something like a skip list.  Having a counter here would be useful, maybe one for each attribute, like countI, countO, countOI, you can then use the counters as keys for the put() function for the skip list.

Once you have found all the attributes then you can move on to writing to csv

```
Stream out = write("filepathname/filename.csv") // to declare the stream
    out << "_I_, _O_, _OI_\n"
```

Then you could loop over your Skip lists at the same time

```
int ijk = 0; bool finito = false
while(!finito) do {
  if(ijk<countI) {
    at = get(skipListI, ijk)
    out << at.name ","
  }
  else out << ","
  if(ijk<countO) {
    at = get(skipListO, ijk)
    out << at.name ","
  }
  else out << ","
  if(ijk<countOI) {
    at = get(skipListOI, ijk)
    out << at.name "\n"
  }
  else out << "\n"

  ijk++
  // check if the next iteration would be outside of bounds on all lists
  if(ijk >= countI && ijk >= countO && ijk >= countIO) finito = true
}
```

Or instead of at.name, you could print out whatever part of the attribute you wanted.  The name, the value, "name:value" or whatever.

I have not run this, so you will be left to do any troubleshooting.

--

I hope this idea gets you started, write out what you want on paper first and then follow that plan.  The key things I have mentioned that would be useful here are Skip lists, and Stream write (or append, if you want to keep adding).

In the future, please consider making your question more clear.  Are you looking for those search terms in the name of the attribute, or in the value of the attribute.  Are you looking to print out the names or the values, or the what?  What kind of format for the .csv are you going to have?  Any information will help your question be answered.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: No problem.  Comment in again if you get stuck.  If you think this sufficiently answers your question, then select it as the accepted answer so that it might help other people in the same situation. :) Best of luck to you!